# Drag-and-drop files onto an NSTableView?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, drag-and-drop

I have an `NSTableView` which I wish to allow users to drag-and-drop video files onto. When they drop the file, it'll get added as a row in the table view.

How would I go about doing this? Currently the tableview's takes its data from an Array Controller (which takes its data from a NSMutableArray)

I found [this](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DragandDrop/Tasks/acceptingdrags.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000993) documentation, but cannot seem to make it work..

I have..

- made a "TableCon" class (which I changed to inherit from NSTableView, not NSObject)
- changed the NSTableView class to TableCon
- set the NSTableView's delegate outlet to that class
- called `registerForDraggedTypes` in TableCon's init
- implemented `- (NSDragOperation)draggingEntered:(id <NSDraggingInfo>)sender;` (again in TableCon)

..but, nothing, it acts like I never changed anything (no errors), what am I doing wrong?

**Edit:** I've tried implementing Boaz Stuller's suggestion, and also found [this](http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/message/cocoa/2009/3/17/232541) description of the solution (the [first reply](http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/message/cocoa/2009/3/17/232543) includes the solution to the first post). So what I have done now is..

- Subclass NSArrayController which feeds content to the table view (TableListCon)
- Add `tableView` outlet to TableListCon (and pointed it at the NSTableView)
- Implement validateDrop, writeRowsWithIndexes, and acceptDrop in TableListCon
- Called registerForDraggedTypes on the tableView outlet.

Again, no errors/warnings, but only the awakeFromNib method seems to be called (None of the other methods are called)

Comment: Those are data source methods.  You need to hook the table view's dataSource outlet to the class that implements those methods in order for them to be called.

Comment: Ohhhhh, that's what I was doing wrong! By "data source" I was assuming it meant the array controller! It's all working perfectly now, could you add that info to your answer so I can accept it? Thanks Boaz!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

NSTableView handles drag-and-drop differently from generic views, which is overall a good thing. It means that you don't have to manually handle the complicated highlighting, cell tracking and inserting behaviours that tables require.

A description of what is required can be found [here](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/TableView/Tasks/UsingDragAndDrop.html). Basically, you still call -registerDraggedTypes: (generally in your -awakeFromNib method) but instead of implementing the NSDraggingDestination methods, you implement the various data source methods associated with drag and drop, which can be found [here](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Protocols/NSTableDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html).  You should not need to subclass NSTableView to implement drag-and-drop in this fashion.

Note those are data source methods. You need to hook the table view's dataSource outlet to the class that implements those methods in order for them to be called.

Comment: Unfortunately, it seems your first link is now dead. I'm not sure what the replacement is.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what Boaz said, it sounds like you're creating an NSTableView subclass and then making an instance of that subclass the delegate of NSTableView. If you're going to subclass, that subclass should be used in place of NSTableView, not in addition to it. Also, it's almost always a violation of concerns to have a view be a delegate for another object.